# How do I stop a script that is running in the background in Qpython3?

Tags: android, qpython, qpython3

I am using Qpython3 on my Android tablet. I have a Python script for a talking alarm clock that I would like to run in the background and then go off at the time the user sets. The problem is, once I set the console running in the background, I can't figure out how to get back to it to stop the script (i.e. get the message to stop repeating).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the "qpython3" app then touch "Console" and in the top left corner touch "No. 1" or "No. 2" or ... then select your background running scripts and by touching "X" sing you can kill them.